# Disable AJAX Update on checkout for WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm using a Custom product Addon so my product is based on the user , he sets his product weight and goes to checkout to calculate his shipping cost based on wegith , problem is the WooCommerce tends to override over this weight and sets the default weight of product which changes the shipping
I'd like to ask how I could disable AJAX at the checkout page (where you enter shipping and billing information) and that instead of using AJAX to update the cart summary based on your location, it would update by doing a natural refresh.
Currently the cart summary would update itself without reloading the page whenever the user switches their location via shipping location. I'd like to remove that AJAX and just have the page reload with the updated information.

i tried to disable AJAX usign this code but didn't work
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review_expired', '__return_false' );